# Multiple domains in nginx without repetitive configuration

Tags: nginx

I have 2 domains names

1. exemple.net
2. exemple.com

and lot of sub-domaines

- demo1.exemple.com
- demo2.exemple.com
- ...
- demo50.exemple.com

Currently I have 50 blocks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name demo1.exemple.*;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name demo2.exemple.*;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        }
}
```

This solution is working but is not really optimized.

I tried to "return" .com instead of .net, to avoid "X" redundancy, but I don't know how to include the sub-domain has a variable.

```
server {
  server_name *.demo.net;
  return 301 http://demo.com$request_uri;
}
```

There should be a way to respect the best practices of nginx, and avoid all this redundancy, but I don't know how to manage the problem.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand what you're trying to accomplish..is one generic server block, which adjusts the `proxy_pass` directive automatically according to the `Host:` header sent by the client what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use a named capture in the `server_name` directive. Something like this:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<name>.+).example.net$;
    return 301 http://$name.example.com$request_uri; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

Comment: Thank  you !
I have solve my second problem too with regex 



server {
    server_name ~^demo(?<num>.+).example.com$;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:810$num;
        }
}

Comment: @Lucastillier You may want to restrict your `$num` capture so that it only matches digits, such as: `(?<num>\d{1,2})`. Place the regex in double quotes if you use `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a lot of websites provided on different ports and you've made each a server block in NginX. If they are completly seperate websites then this is the only way I think.
However, if the sites are all served under one root folder, you should make only one server block with the name of all the domain names.

I'll get burned and killed because of this, but I would consider using IF to check the domain name and redirect the users according to it. And I know... IF IS EVIL!